# Difficulty in understanding the provided input facebook hacker cup 2017

Tags: algorithm

Problem: Fighting the zombie
An example/sample input is given. This question is about understanding it. I have created the program, out of 5 cases 3 are going correct. The other 2 are case number 2 and 4.

Here is how I am thinking about the problem.
In case #2 there are 2 spells.
Value of H: 10
1st spell: 10d6-10 
Values will be between 0 and 50.
Value greater than equal to 10 will kill the zombie so. Number of values is 41.
So probability is 41/51 = 0.803921
But the answer is given 0.998520
Can you explain me where I am wrong?

Comment: Your question is lacking the statement of the problem. You may want to add it to your question, as not everyone in StackOverflow is a participant of Facebook HackerCup and it may increase your odds of getting a response.

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not 1-50. you need to actually roll the dice. then you'll see that some values appear multiple times and some don't appear at all.

once you've got that right, the issue becomes one of efficiency coz you can't simply brute force your way through 20d20 for example